# multiple form dont update mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function an first query working fine
but second is multiple form like input name="id[]" ,urunad="id[]",birim="id[]"...
I take $_POST to function

```
$id2 = $gid;
$sid2 = $sid; 
$urunad2 = $urunad;
$birim2 = $birim;
$adet2 = $adet;
$fiyat2 = $fiyat;
$kdvsiztoplam2 = $kdvsiztoplam; 
whats the problem please help me


     public function updateData($kasano,$gid,$sturu,$firmaid,$firmaadi,$vergid,$vergin,$adres,$telefon,$email,$sid,$urunad,$birim,$adet,$fiyat,$kdvsiztoplam,$kdv,$aratoplam,$geneltoplam,$kdvtutar,$kdvdahil,$tarih)
            {
                    $query = $this->db->prepare("update siparis set kasano = ? ,sturu = ? ,firmaid = ? ,firmaadi = ? ,vergid = ? ,vergin = ? ,adres = ? ,telefon = ? ,email = ? ,kdv = ? ,aratoplam = ? ,geneltoplam = ? ,kdvtutar = ? ,kdvdahil = ? ,tarih = ?");
                    $update = $query->execute(array($kasano,$sturu,$firmaid,$firmaadi,$vergid,$vergin,$adres,$telefon,$email,$kdv,$aratoplam,$geneltoplam,$kdvtutar,$kdvdahil,$tarih));
                    return $update;


                    $id2 = $gid;
                    $sid2 = $sid;   
                    $urunad2 = $urunad;
                    $birim2 = $birim;
                    $adet2 = $adet;
                    $fiyat2 = $fiyat;
                    $kdvsiztoplam2 = $kdvsiztoplam; 


                for($i=0;$i<count($id2);$i++)
                {
                    $query = $this->db->prepare("update surunler set id = ? ,sid = ?,urunad = ? ,birim = ? ,adet = ? ,fiyat = ? ,kdvsiztoplam = ? ");
                    $update = $query->execute(array($id2[$i],$sid2[$i],$urunad2[$i],$birim2[$i],$adet2[$i],$fiyat2[$i],$kdvsiztoplam2[$i]));
                    return $update;
                }


            }
```

Comment: Should there be something like a `WHERE...` clause on the UPDATES?

Comment: thanks your reply but I try this dont work         $query = $this->db->prepare("update surunler set sid = ?,urunad = ? ,birim = ? ,adet = ? ,fiyat = ? ,kdvsiztoplam = ? where = ".$id2."");
        $update = $query->execute(array($sid2[$i],$urunad2[$i],$birim2[$i],$adet2[$i],$fiyat2[$i],$kdvsiztoplam2[$i]));
        return $update;

Comment: You need to define the column you are comparing `id2` to. Also `return` is going to execute your function when encountered.

Answer (score 0):

When you type "return" in PHP the entire function is aborted at that point and control returned to the calling function.

This means nothing below the first query will run.

Secondly, a return in a for loop does not apply to the for loop as it does in some languages, it still will abort the entire function and return control to the calling function.

Answer (score -1):

thanks your help working code here maybe someone need help

```
    public function updateData($kasano,$gid,$sturu,$firmaid,$firmaadi,$vergid,$vergin,$adres,$telefon,$email,$sid,$urunad,$birim,$adet,$fiyat,$kdvsiztoplam,$kdv,$aratoplam,$geneltoplam,$kdvtutar,$kdvdahil,$tarih)
{
        $query = $this->db->prepare("update siparis set kasano = ? ,sturu = ? ,firmaid = ? ,firmaadi = ? ,vergid = ? ,vergin = ? ,adres = ? ,telefon = ? ,email = ? ,kdv = ? ,aratoplam = ? ,geneltoplam = ? ,kdvtutar = ? ,kdvdahil = ? ,tarih = ?");
        $update = $query->execute(array($kasano,$sturu,$firmaid,$firmaadi,$vergid,$vergin,$adres,$telefon,$email,$kdv,$aratoplam,$geneltoplam,$kdvtutar,$kdvdahil,$tarih));



        $id2 = $gid;
        $sid2 = $sid;   
        $urunad2 = $urunad;
        $birim2 = $birim;
        $adet2 = $adet;
        $fiyat2 = $fiyat;
        $kdvsiztoplam2 = $kdvsiztoplam; 


    for($i=0;$i<count($id2);$i++)
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("update surunler set sid = ?,urunad = ? ,birim = ? ,adet = ? ,fiyat = ? ,kdvsiztoplam = ? where id = ?");
        $update = $query->execute(array($sid2[$i],$urunad2[$i],$birim2[$i],$adet2[$i],$fiyat2[$i],$kdvsiztoplam2[$i],$id2[$i]));
    }


}
```

Comment: In which case, please accept the answer that was correct. That's how you give thanks on SO and also let others know if they have the same problem.